# View All permutation In Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have list of data for example { X, Y, Z}
I want to to create list that has the following options without repetition {X, XY, XYZ, Y, YZ, Z}.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please read the [help]  before posting

Comment: Not clear what `X`, `Y` and `Z` are. Anyway i don't see any "permutations" here.

Comment: Did you mean subset of the given set, then backtracking is the key

Answer (score 1):

You can create all subsets of a set using backtracking algorithm.

```java
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<>();
        helper(result, current, nums, 0);
        return result;
    }
    public void helper(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> current, int [] nums, int start) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
        for (int i=start; i<nums.length; i++) {
            // select an element
            current.add(nums[i]);
            // recursively go for the next element
            helper(result, current, nums, i+1);
            // undo the last selection
            current.remove(current.size()-1);
        }
    }
```

Note : Here I considered the elements to be integer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is a `float[]`, this does what you want:

```
float[] arr;
for(int i = 0; i != arr.length; i += 1) {
  for(int j = i; j != arr.length; j += 1) {

    // What you want now is the slice of all values arr[i]..arr[j]
    for(int z = i; z != j+1; z += 1) {
      System.out.print(arr[i]);
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the null set and XZ are not mentioned, I assume that the OP is requesting for a ***list of all the non-empty subsequences*** of a given `String`.

Here is a naive non-efficient way of doing it. For a more efficient approach, have a look at [this GeeksForGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-subsequences-string/).

```
void printAllPermutations(String inputString) {
    int lengthOfString = inputString.length();
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < lengthOfString; j++) {
            resultList.add(inputString.substring(i, j + 1));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultList);
}
```